# Spring boot POST API default behavior in terms of security

Tags: spring-boot, curl, ssl-certificate

I have a following curl command that when hit:

```
curl --location '<some endpoint>' \
--header 'client_id: <some client id>' \
--header 'client_secret: <some secret>' \
--header 'messageId: <some message id>'
```

gives the following issues(screenshots attached):

**curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not establish a secure connection to it.
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name**

[server legitimacy issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GlH1.png)

[ssl issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTu2a.png)

However when I use -k in the command, I get a successful response

I need to know what would happen if I hit the same endpoint using spring boot rest template? Does spring boot by default use -k(ignoring certificate issue) or it will fail the way it happened as above.

As per my research so far, I think it would fail. However, can some one share their expertise?

P.S. I can't hit the endpoint since it's a client provided endpoint and I am doing a POC first before finally coming up with my findings.

Comment: `-k` means insecure, which doesn't do SSL validation. By default the SSL configuration for Java (and thus spring boot) will do validation and thus will fail